# Jquery hover, highlight table row except last cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, highlight

I want to convert this css behaviour into a jquery hover statement (because IE7/8 doesn't support css3). Basically when hovering over a row, I want the whole row to be highlighted except for the last cell.

```
#mysearchtable tr:hover td:not(:last-child)
{
  background-color: #444444;
}
```

I've tried using this:

```
$("#mysearchtable tr td:not(:last-child)").hover(
 function () { $(this).addClass('hoverclass') }, 
 function () { $(this).removeClass('hoverclass') });
```

The problem with this is $(this) is only returning the actual cell that was hovered over. I can try and use $(this).parent() but that would give me the whole row. What I want is the highlight the whole row, except the last cell.

Would anyone know a solution?

Cheers.

Comment: $(this).siblings().find('td:not(:last-child)').add/removeClass() ? didn't check but see no reason not to work.

Comment: Your CSS selector is wrong.

Use `#mysearchtable tr td:not(:last-child):hover`

With your original selector your saying "Highlight the row, but don't highlight the last cell", which doesn't make sense, because you're highlighting the container(row) not the individual cells within the container.

Comment: That's not what his selector is saying. It's "When the row is hovered, highlight the cells, but not the last one." Yours is, "When a cell that isn't the last one is hovered".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested, but try:

```
$("#mysearchtable tr").hover(
    function () { $(this).find("td:not(:last-child)").addClass('hoverclass') }, 
    function () { $(this).find("td:not(:last-child)").removeClass('hoverclass') }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use this way. [Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cbAdb/)

```
$("table td").not('td:last').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color','red');
});
```

​